# Access Denied when listing object using amazon s3 client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, lambda

From the aws lambda I want to list objects inside s3 bucket. When testing the function locally I'm getting access denied error.

```
public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
{
  var secretKey = "***";
  var uid = "***";
  var bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
  AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(uid, secretKey);

  ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
  listObjectsRequest.BucketName = bucketName;
  var listObjectsResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(listObjectsRequest); 
  // exception is thrown
  ...
}
```

> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied   at
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionStream(IRequestContext
> requestContext, IWebResponseData httpErrorResponse,
> HttpErrorResponseException exception, Stream responseStream)    at
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionAsync(IExecutionContext
> executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) ....

The bucket I'm using in this example "my-bucket-name" is `Publicly accessible` and it has
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IAM policies are a preferred way how to control access to S3 buckets.

For S3 permissions it is always very important to distinguish between bucket level actions and object level actions and also - who is calling that action. In your code I can see that you do use ListObjects, which is a bucket level action, so that is OK.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

What did catch my I is the following:

```
  var secretKey = "***";
  var uid = "***";
  var bucketName = "my-bucket-name";
  AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(uid, secretKey);
```

That means that you are using for your access an AWS role. But even in your screenshot you can see that "Authenticated users group (anyone with an AWS account)" does not have any permissions assigned.

If you already have a role I would suggest to give the read-bucket permissions to that particular role (user) via an IAM policy. But adding read  ACL to your AWS users should help as well.